# Chrome find bar closing on macOS Sierra

Tags: google-chrome, macos

Previously on Chrome, I could use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the Chrome find bar, then <kbd>esc</kbd> would close it. However, on macOS Sierra, <kbd>esc</kbd> now exits full-screen mode if the Chrome window is in this mode (which I commonly use).

What is the shortcut to close the find bar? Alternatively, how do I disable <kbd>esc</kbd> closing full-screen mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround to close the find bar is to use `Fn + Esc`, rather then `Esc`.

---

However, you can easily prevent Chrome to close the full-sceen mode by pressing `Esc` through this script (following [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/315949/dont-exit-full-screen-when-pressing-escape-in-apps-like-safari-on-lion)):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Keep Full Screen
// @namespace     https://superuser.com/q/315949
// @description    Prevents Escape key from leaving full screen.
// @include      http://*
// ==/UserScript==
document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) evt.preventDefault();
}
```

To run this, you can use the [NinjaKit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ninjakit/gpbepnljaakggeobkclonlkhbdgccfek?hl=it) Google Chrome extension.